# Page is not displaying in Microsoft Edge using Form tag in jsp

Tags: html, jsp, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, x-ua-compatible

As per my project requirement plan to move Microsoft edge and it is working fine in IE7 and when I tested the attached code in Microsoft Edge and even IE 11 it is not showing the page and I went multiple websites and they mentioned Form attribute not supported in Edge and 11.Not sure about this.In this case what need to change in my code.Thanks in Advance.

I tried to execute in lower verison it is working and in IE11 and edge it is not working.

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.*,com.bean.*"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
  <%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net"%>

      <s:actionerror />
       <s:fielderror />
   <s:url var="css" value="/styles/abc.css" includeContext="false" />
       <form id="abcAction" name="abcAction" action="/abcAction.action" 
                    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   <div id="abcFieldSet">
                  <div class="abcCriteria">
                  <s:hidden name="batchType" value="XF" />
                 <s:hidden name="flag" value="true" />
                 <ul>
              <li><label>Code:</label><s:textfield id="LocationID" 
                    name="Location" theme="simple" cssClass="abcFont" 
                     cssStyle="text- transform: uppercase;" /></li>
             <li><label>Id:</label><s:textfield id="requestorID" 
               name="Id" theme="simple" cssClass="abcFont" cssStyle="text- 
                    transform: uppercase;" /></li>
                 </ul>
                </div>

                    <div class="searchCriteria">
                    <ul>
            <li><label>Error Message:</label><s:textfield 
                      id="errorMsgID" name="errorMsg" theme="simple" cssClass="abcFont" /></li>
    <li><label>Status:</label><s:select id="statusFlagID" 
           headerKey="-1" headerValue="-Select Status-" 
                list="statusFlagList" name="statusFlag" theme="simple" 
               cssClass="abcFont"/></li>
</ul>
</div>
<br class="clear" />
<p><s:submit name="abcSearchAction"   action="abcSearchAction" type="button" theme="simple" title="Search" label="Search" />
   <s:reset name="clearFields" type="reset" value="Clear" theme="simple" title="Clear" label="Clear" onclick="return clearSearchform();" /></p>
</div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Did you see any error on the web page or in console while running the jsp page? Did you try to run this web page in other browsers like chrome or firefox? if yes, does it work? for testing purpose, try to create new project and try to add form in it and try to run it to check whether it works or not. Let us know about your testing results.

Comment: i tried in other browser like chrome or firefox both it is not working

Comment: Which means it is not a MS Edge browser specific issue. It can be the issue with your JSP page. you can try to check it and correct page should work with majority of browsers.

Comment: but it is working fine in IE7

Comment: Try to add this line in your code. <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> and again test with Edge browser to see whether it loads the page or not.